# Absolute path (www.example.com) in file_put_contents

Tags: php

There is one question on this website that is similar to mine but I couldn't get any help from that. What I'm trying to achevie is make ONE visitors.txt file and save it in the root directory. I'm trying to figure out a way to do it but I couldn't find **any** hhelp as there is no question that is similar to mine on this site.

So basically, I'm trying to log a file with guests IP and stuff on my website.

My code:

```
  $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$line = date('d-m-Y - h:i:s A') . " - $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] ----->  " . "$actual_link";


file_put_contents ('visitors.txt', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
      }
```

This code makes a new 'visitors.txt' file in every new directory. In other words, if there will be a new `visitors.txt` file in the /users directory, a new `visitors.txt` file in the /users/publish direcotory, etc.

I just want one `visitors.txt` and that is in the root directory.

I have tried adding the `realpath` thing to my code but no help.

```
    $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$line = date('d-m-Y - h:i:s A') . " - $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] ----->  " . "$actual_link";


file_put_contents(realpath('http://example.com/') . 'visitors.txt', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
      }
```

Comment: you cannot put files with `file_put_contents` using http protocol

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What exactly do I have to do to save it in the root directory?

Comment: Use a file system path instead of an URL.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to PHP. How would I convert a URL to file system path or how wold I implement it to my code?